# What does the following matrix inequality mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a collection of $m\times m$ matrices.  I'm trying to understand the following criteria: There exists $\lambda\in[0,1)$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$
$$ \lambda \sum_{i=1}^n |A_ix|^2 \ge \sum_{i\ne j} |\langle A_ix,A_jx\rangle|.$$ I don't understand the significance of this inequality or what it means for this collection of matrices. This appears as an assumption in a paper involving PDEs, where the $A_i$'s are related to the principal symbol of the operator (although not in the obvious way), but I think I just want to understand how to interpret this statement in general if possible.